# economic circuit

Tags: tikz-pgf, pstricks, circuitikz

Having seen some examples of electronic circuits, I would like to make an economic one like this one:

[image]

I haven't found any relevant example, so would like your help.

In case that somebody is interested in economics, a more representative circular flow is the following one:
[image]

While I was trying to create the second figure I met a problem and my code doesn't work.

```
    \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
    \usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
    \usepackage{ucs} 
    \usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{tkz-tab}
    \usetikzlibrary{shapes,snakes}
    \usepackage{smartdiagram}
    \usepackage{geometry}
    \usetikzlibrary{positioning}
    \geometry{left=0.75in,right=0.75in,top=0.65in,bottom=0.65in}
    \usepackage{tkz-euclide}
    \usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
        \usepackage{tkz-fct} \usetkzobj{all}
    \usetikzlibrary{calc,decorations.pathreplacing}
    \usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usepackage{verbatim}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
    \usepackage{filecontents}
    \usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (c1)[shape=circle,draw]  {
   $\left.
      \begin{array}{c}
        \textit{Επιχειρήσεις}\\
        \textit{\footnotesize (Παραγωγοί)} \\
      \end{array}
\right.
$  
    };
 \node[rectangle,draw,rounded corners] (c2) [right=of c1] {Κράτος}; 
\node (c3) [shape=circle,draw]   [right=of c2] {
    $\left.
      \begin{array}{c}
        \textit{Νοικοκυριά}\\
        \textit{\footnotesize (Καταναλωτές)} \\
      \end{array}
    \right.
    $
    };
\node(c4)[shape=circle,draw, above=of c2]  {
    $\left.
      \begin{array}{c}
        \textit{Αγορά}\\
        \textit{Αγαθών}\\ \textit{Υπηρεσιών}
      \end{array}
    \right.
    $
    };

\node (c5)[shape=circle,draw, below=of c2]  {
    $\left.
      \begin{array}{c}
        \textit{Αγορά}\\
        \textit{Παραγωγικών} \\
\textit{Συντελεστών}
      \end{array}
    \right.
    $
    };

\draw [<-,thick,color=Green] (c4) to [bend right=45]  (c1);
\draw [<-,thick,color=Green] (c3) to [bend right=45]  (c4);
\draw [<-,thick,color=Green] (c5) to [bend right=45]  (c3);
\draw [<-,thick,color=Green] (c1) to [bend right=45]  (c5);

\draw [->,thick, color=Red,postaction={decorate,decoration={raise=5ex,text along path,text align=center,text={ Δ}}}]      (c4) to [bend left=45] (c1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}


\end{document}
```

Comment: My 2 cents: you could use gnuplot instead, but I think you could only get rectangles and straight lines.

Comment: this will be very straight forward in `tikz` or `pstricks`- the example at the beginning of `3.1` of the `pgf` manual should get you started- it'd be great if you could try that, post your code, and then ask for help on any areas that you're stuck with :)

Comment: I seriously doubt `circuitikz` is of any help here, but it certainly is quite straightforward to do in `tikz`.

Comment: The other examples looks like something that can also be done in TikZ very easily. It is also possible to (ab)use `tikz-cd` for that … A `\matrix` or the `positioning` library are helpful tools.

Comment: TikZ won't allow you create that ugliness and giving up error based on its own horror :)

Comment: Unfortunately on my machine it doesn't do the same justice and compiles without any errors.

Comment: @percusse do you have any suggestions about how to turn this ugliness into a beautiness?

Comment: Ugliness aside, that is a peculiarly unhelpful diagram. It is hard to make any sense of it at all. That is, insofar as I can make some sense of it, I have to import knowledge to figure out what the diagram probably wants to mean. I can then try to map that back in an attempt to figure out how it is trying to convey that meaning. Doing that, I'd say it makes about 1/3 sense to me, 2/3 I write off as a lost cause.

Comment: Not sure how the code relates to the target picture. It does not compile for me. Is that what you mean by 'doesn't work'? If so, the problem is ` Δ` in the decoration text. At least. replacing that by `t` worked.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 14):

The `circuits` library is not really suited for this kind of diagram.

This can easily be achieved with three nodes and a few edges. The `shapes.geometric` library provides the `ellipse` shape.

The `auto=right` option positions all nodes along a path on the right side (the default is left). The `swap` option changes this for only one node to the other side.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz, convert=false]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  main node/.style={
    draw,
    shape=ellipse,
    minimum width=2cm,
    minimum height=1cm
  },
  >=latex,
  auto=right
]
  \node[main node] (daervz) {daervz};
  \node[main node] (y) at  (50:4) {y};
  \node[main node] (x) at (130:4) {x};

  \path[
    nodes={font=\scriptsize},
    ->
  ] (x)      edge[bend left=50]  node[swap] {Goods} (y)
             edge[bend right=50] node       {ddaf}  (daervz)
             edge[bend right=10] node[swap] {z}     (y)
    (daervz) edge[bend right=50] node       {dddda} (y)
             edge[bend left]     node       {dda}   (x)
    (y)      edge[bend left]     node       {dda}   (daervz)
             edge[bend left]     node       {k}     (x)
             edge[bend right]    node       {z}     (x)
  ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Answer (score 12):

With PSTricks. Just for fun!

```
\documentclass[preview,border={10pt 10pt 10pt 40pt}]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\def\obj#1{\makebox[1cm]{\strut#1}}

\begin{document}
\offinterlineskip
\begin{psmatrix}[colsep=1cm,rowsep=3cm,mnode=oval]
    [name=l]\obj{x} & & [name=r]\obj{y}\\
        & [name=b]\obj{daervz} \\
\end{psmatrix}
\psset{arrows=->}
% upper connections
\ncarc[arcangle=40]{l}{r}\naput{Goods}
\ncarc[arcangle=-20]{r}{l}\nbput[labelsep=3pt]{z}
\ncarc[arcangle=-20]{l}{r}\naput{z}
\ncarc[arcangle=50]{r}{l}\nbput[labelsep=3pt]{k}
% left connections
\ncarc[arcangle=-50]{l}{b}\nbput{ddaf}
\ncarc[arcangle=20]{b}{l}\nbput{dda}
% right connections
\ncarc[arcangle=-50]{b}{r}\nbput{dddda}
\ncarc[arcangle=20]{r}{b}\nbput{dda}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Simplified version:

We can save more keystroke by using `shortput=nab` option as follows.

```
\documentclass[preview,border={10pt 10pt 10pt 40pt}]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\def\obj#1{\makebox[1cm]{\strut#1}}

\begin{document}
\offinterlineskip
\begin{psmatrix}[colsep=1cm,rowsep=3cm,mnode=oval]
    [name=l]\obj{x} & & [name=r]\obj{y}\\
        & [name=b]\obj{daervz} \\
\end{psmatrix}
\psset{arrows=->,shortput=nab}
% upper connections
\ncarc[arcangle=40]{l}{r}^{Goods}
\ncarc[arcangle=-20]{r}{l}_[labelsep=3pt]{z}
\ncarc[arcangle=-20]{l}{r}^{z}
\ncarc[arcangle=50]{r}{l}_[labelsep=3pt]{k}
% left connections
\ncarc[arcangle=-50]{l}{b}_{ddaf}
\ncarc[arcangle=20]{b}{l}_{dda}
% right connections
\ncarc[arcangle=-50]{b}{r}_{dddda}
\ncarc[arcangle=20]{r}{b}_{dda}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It shows me an error: Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \c@lor@to@ps

Comment: @giannis: Compile it with `latex-dvips-ps2pdf` steps.